# Timezone settings problem in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am trying to setup CodeIgniter on my WAMP with PHP 5.3.5 and 2.0.2 CI. My "Hello World" application run successfully (I had only a controller and view). Next I added a Model test.php

```
class Tests extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {    
        parent::__contruct();
    }
}
```

I instantiate the model in my controller as:

```
$this->load->model('Tests');
```

But I keep getting this error:[image]

> It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.

How do I resolve this error? I tried setting date.timezone property in php.ini. I also tried calling `date_default_timezone_set` method in index.php of CI. I did go through CI forum but everybody seems to have fixed the issue by calling `date_default_timezone_set`. But when I call the method, I don't even get the error. Instead, I get an 500 server error response from Apache!

PHP & CI experts.. I need your help.

---

**Latest Update**

I enabled logging to see how things run under the mat. Here is my model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Hello extends CI_Model {

        function __construct()
        {
            log_message('debug', "Staring Hello Model");
            parent::__construct();
            log_message('debug', "Done with Hello Model");
        }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        //$this->load->view('hello');
        echo phpinfo(); 
    }

    public function newfun()
    {
        log_message('debug', "Starting new method...");
        $this->load->model('hello');
        log_message('debug', "Completed model load...");
        $this->load->view('hello');
    }
}
```

And my log file:

```
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Starting new method...
DEBUG - 2011-04-18 15:01:44 --> Model Class Initialized
```

The last log output comes from the constructor of Model.php in ci/system/core folder. There is no indication of my model's controller being executed (I don't see any log message from the model).

What's wrong with my Model? Am I coding it correctly or overlooking something silly?

Comment: Is there any code in your model that calls any date functions? Can you paste the entire construct code please?

Comment: I have provided the complete code! there is no properties or methods other than constructor. I plan to use the model later to fetch data from DB...

Comment: Woah that is weird! What happens if you remove the parent::_construct code?

Comment: No change.. I even posted it on CI forum http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/186740/

Comment: But the minute you remove the load->model in your controller the problem goes away?

Comment: Yup.. just comment the load->model and problem goes away!

Comment: I'm stumped. I can only suggest to backup any work you have done thus far, and reinstall CI from scratch, following the instructions step by step

Comment: I know it's not ideal. I just had a look into the core model.php file, it's extremely basic. Maybe place a few echo's in there, say, 1 just inside the constructor, one midway, one at the end. And see where it is getting tripped up?

Comment: thanks for the tip.. :) Will do that too

Comment: Let me know how it goes.. I use CI alot and it would be interesting for me and others to see the solution.

Comment: I have some weired findings.. please refer my updated question

Comment: Whats the filename of the model?

Comment: Model: hello.php ; Controller: hello.php View: hello.php .. will that cause any issue?

Comment: Can you try, out of interest, the following, 'goodbye_model.php' (lowercase) and the main line of the model 'class Goodbye_model extends CI_Model' and load 'Goodbye_model' (uppercase first)

Comment: WAALAA!!! I can't believe my eyes!!! What kind of magic word is "goodbye_model"??? Its working!

Comment: Can i post that as an answer?

Comment: Definitely!.. go ahead. and I will close the question..

Comment: Posted answer. Goodluck with the rest of the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a naming conflict? Or a naming issue (CI is very specific about lowercase upper case in model/controller and view names).

Can you try, 'goodbye_model.php' (lowercase) and the main line of the model 'class Goodbye_model extends CI_Model' and load 'Goodbye_model' (uppercase first).

And ensure the filename is lowercase, and the class name is first upper case.